# Sharepoint not connecting to sql server when reconnecting to farm after renaming SQL server

Tags: sql-server, rename

Yesterday, I renamed my Sharepoint server in Windows. When I logged in this morning, 90% of it was working - pretty much all but the Excel service.

While troubleshooting, one suggestion was to remove the Sharepoint server from the farm, and rerun the configuration wizard.

Now, when I run the wizard, I get an error saying `Failed to connect to the database server. Look at the logs for more information.`

I then looked at the logs, and see the following error:

```
    An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown. Additional exception information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Comment: How many servers in farm? How you rename the server, method?

Comment: 1 sharepoint server, and 1 sql server. I renamed the windows machine name.  After I was researching the issues today, I tried 'rename-SPServer', but that failed

Comment: Are u able to connect to sql server from the sharepoint server? This error says either the account don't have permission or server unable to connect sql

Comment: I can't connect at all to sql server from the sharepoint server, but I can from other servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that the Sharepoint server was in a different subdomain than the Windows server. Once I moved it, I was able to connect. However, Sharepoint refused to recognize Sharepoint_Config as a valid configuration database, so I ended up creating a whole new farm